# Android: delete null rows from recycler view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

So i have a user-input and a button. When user enters for example some text and button is clicked, another activity cames up and loads the user-input in a recyclerView.
The problem is that somehow my recycler view adds some null rows as you can see in this picture.

Is there any piece of code that fix this error?
[image]
this is my adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextViewLine1;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewLine1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line1);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mTextViewLine1.setText(currentItem.getLine1());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all add the image to your question, second you must provide the adapter code atleast.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam you are right. I just add the image and  the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hard to tell from your adapter code, could be something with your search. But try this and see what happens:**

```
//in the adapter constructor

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
     mExampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleItem>();

    for(int i=0 ; i<exampleList.size() ; i++){
      ExampleItem item = exampleList.get(i);
      if(item.getLine1() != null && !item.getLine1().isEmpty()){
       mExampleList.add(item);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: something like that is what i'v tried before..Also your code gives me "cannot resolve symbol position". But i think its close to what i need.

Comment: I mean `i` not `position`